# Is there a feature in Postman that runs a test only once before all others

Tags: javascript, rest, mocha.js, postman

In mocha there are the `before` and `after` functions that you can use to set up and tear down testing suites. Is there a similar feature in Postman? I want to get an apikey without having to run the request every single time I iterate through a collection.

Comment: See if pre-request scripts can be of any help - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/jetpacks_pre_request_scripts

Comment: That is also not what I am talking about. I am talking about a request that runs once at the beginning to do setup and then doesn't run for the rest of the iterations.

Comment: @toshiomagic - did you find a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's a paid feature of the new [Postman Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop). You are probably still using the old legacy version.

Comment: How do you implement it? I don't see it in the documentation.

Comment: There's a guide [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/).

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. Also, I am using the very latest version of the packaged app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a folder in your collection and move it to the top of the collection and that will have it run and collect all the data like cookie or bearer token that you need for the other tests. You can also set up a folder at the end called breakdown that will clean up all your work.

[image]